# File writing, difference in insertion operator and write function?

Tags: c++

I want to know that what's the difference between **insertion operator (<<)** and function **write ()**, Because of the code of lines given below

```
outFile << "Hello world";
```

And

```
outFile.write("Hello world");
```

Both of these achieved desired results for me, when I was trying to write string "Hello world" in text file. So what's difference between both of these? 
And why we need write () function when insertion operator can write in file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write()` is unformated output and only takes a `const char *` and int. It also doesn't set failbit on failure. For more information, look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write). Operator `<<` has formatted and unformatted overloads.

Answer (score 1):

> So what's difference between both of these?

The main difference is that the second won't compile. `write` has two parameters, and is used for writing a sequence of characters with a known size:

```
outFile.write("Hello world", 11);
```

Use this *unformatted output* when you already have an array containing the sequence of characters you want to output.

The insertion operator, for *formatted output*, is used to format many different types (including zero-terminated strings, as in your example). For example:

```
outFile << "Hello world";  // outputs the string (no need to specify the size)
outFile << 42;             // outputs "42", formatting the integer as text
```

Comment: :v nice, off course it wont compile. But still i am not able to understand about insertion operator?
Please explain it more.

Comment: @shujat7: `<<` will take any input: string, int, char*, whathaveyou, convert it to string and then write it. (Of course, if the type can t be implicitely converted, it will fail).

Comment: @shujat7: I've added a couple of examples of the use of `<<`. It's used when you want the stream to figure out how to format whatever type you output (numeric types, pointers, `std::string`, C-style strings like your example, and any other type with a suitable overload of `<<`).