# Difference between operator<< and write function?

Tags: c++, c-strings, cout, outputstream

I wonder what is the difference between `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<` and `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::write`. What about performance?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string tempMsg;
    tempMsg.reserve( 100 );
    tempMsg += "This is a string";

    std::cout.write( tempMsg.data( ), tempMsg.size( ) ).write( "\n", 1 );
    std::cout << tempMsg << '\n';
}
```

They both print the same string. But what are the advantages of each of them?

Comment: Check out cppreference.com for a start.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I did. But I could not find anything regarding possible performance differences.

Comment: does this clear your question :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24530023/12299208

Comment: `write` allows you to output only part of a string: `std::cout.write("Hello", 4);`; `operator<<` provides many overloads and the same syntax may be used for calling the member operator and a custom implementation as a free function for a custom type. There's a good chance that `operator<<` is internally invokes `write`. As for the performance: There's just too much stuff going on "under the hood" of the compiler to tell for shure; It's best to measure things like these, but in this case this can be problematic, since io is involved which may not have the most reliable performance.

Comment: @Sayan Dasgupta Yes, it was helpful.

Comment: What's the point of `tempMsg.reserve(100);` in your code? Are you aware this will **not** change the size of the string? Perhaps you intended to write [`tempMsg.resize(100);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) instead?

Comment: @heap underrun I reserve some capacity cause the string will be bigger than the small string buffer on my compiler ( 16 bytes for GCC ) so that it gets allocated once on the heap and does not reallocate itself each time something is appended to it.

Comment: @digito_evo OK, then it is a valid usage of `reserve`, but totally unrelated to the question you are asking. Usually we expect the question to provide a [mre] without any irrelevant code, so that's why I got suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function allows to specify the number of characters to be outputted for a character array.

For example of you have declaration

```
const char *s = "Hello World!";
```

and want to output only the word "Hello" from the string literal then you can write

```
std::cout.write( s, 5 );
```

If you will write

```
std::cout << s;
```

then the whole string literal will be outputted.

Thus using the function you can output any part of a character array as for example

```
std::cout. write( s + 6, 2 ) << 'w' << s + 11 << '\n';
```

As for the performance then there is no difference or the difference is insignificant. What is important is the functionality.